# SQL Combine 4 Tables with 4 columns that have the same data and 1 unique column from each table

Tags: mysql, join, multiple-columns

Newbie Question:
I have 4 Tables which have 4 similar data column types along with multiple columns that are unique to each table.  To make it easier to explain I will only include 1 unique column per query.

I want to summarize the data by MonthDate, Department, Category, Subcategory and then each unique column from each query.

For the Date, Department, Category, Subcategory each query will have some of the combinations but none will have all of them.

I just can't figure out how to combine them properly and optimally.

Query from Sales

```
SELECT SalesDate, DeptCode, CatCode, SubCatCode, SUM(SalesUnits)
FROM SalesTable 
GROUP BY DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, SalesDate), 0), DeptCode, CatCode, SubCatCode

╔══════╦══════╦══════╦══════╦══════╗
║ DATE ║ DPT  ║ CAT  ║ SUB  ║ SLS  ║
╠══════╬══════╬══════╬══════╬══════╣
║ 10/1 ║ 01   ║ 35   ║ 3548 ║ 11   ║
║ 11/1 ║ 01   ║ 35   ║ 3556 ║ 14   ║
╚══════╩══════╩══════╩══════╩══════╝
```

Query from Buy Table

```
SELECT BuyDate, DeptCode, CatCode, SubCatCode, SUM(BuyUnits)
FROM BuyTable 
GROUP BY DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, BuyDate), 0), DeptCode, CatCode, SubCatCode

╔══════╦══════╦══════╦══════╦══════╗
║ DATE ║ DPT  ║ CAT  ║ SUB  ║ BUY  ║
╠══════╬══════╬══════╬══════╬══════╣
║ 10/1 ║ 01   ║ 35   ║ 3548 ║ 17   ║
║ 11/1 ║ 01   ║ 35   ║ 3567 ║ 10   ║
╚══════╩══════╩══════╩══════╩══════╝
```

Query from Adjustments Table

```
SELECT AdjustDate, DeptCode, CatCode, SubCatCode, SUM(AdjustmentUnits)
FROM AdjustmentTable 
GROUP BY DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, AdjustDate), 0), DeptCode, CatCode, SubCatCode

╔══════╦══════╦══════╦══════╦══════╗
║ DATE ║ DPT  ║ CAT  ║ SUB  ║ ADJ  ║
╠══════╬══════╬══════╬══════╬══════╣
║ 10/1 ║ 01   ║ 35   ║ 3556 ║  5   ║
║ 11/1 ║ 01   ║ 35   ║ 3567 ║  3   ║
╚══════╩══════╩══════╩══════╩══════╝
```

Query from Discount Table

```
SELECT DiscountDate, DeptCode, CatCode, SubCatCode, SUM(DiscountAmount)
FROM DiscountTable 
GROUP BY DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, DiscountDate), 0), DeptCode, CatCode, SubCatCode

╔══════╦══════╦══════╦══════╦══════╗
║ DATE ║ DPT  ║ CAT  ║ SUB  ║ DSC  ║
╠══════╬══════╬══════╬══════╬══════╣
║ 10/1 ║ 01   ║ 40   ║ 4014 ║  75  ║
║ 11/1 ║ 01   ║ 35   ║ 3567 ║  23  ║
╚══════╩══════╩══════╩══════╩══════╝
```

I would like it summarized as follows:

```
╔══════╦══════╦══════╦══════╦══════╦══════╦══════╦══════╗
║ DATE ║ DPT  ║ CAT  ║ SUB  ║ SLS  ║ BUY  ║ ADJ  ║ DSC  ║
╠══════╬══════╬══════╬══════╬══════╬══════╬══════╬══════╣
║ 10/1 ║ 01   ║ 35   ║ 3548 ║ 11   ║ 17   ║ NULL ║ NULL ║
║ 10/1 ║ 01   ║ 35   ║ 3556 ║ NULL ║ NULL ║  5   ║ NULL ║
║ 10/1 ║ 01   ║ 40   ║ 4014 ║ NULL ║ NULL ║ NULL ║  75  ║
║ 11/1 ║ 01   ║ 35   ║ 3556 ║ 14   ║ NULL ║ NULL ║ NULL ║
║ 11/1 ║ 01   ║ 35   ║ 3567 ║ NULL ║ 10   ║  3   ║  23  ║
╚══════╩══════╩══════╩══════╩══════╩══════╩══════╩══════╝
```

This seemed to Work for me:

```
SELECT COALESCE(T1.MDate, T2.MDate, T3.MDate, T4.MDate) MDate
, COALESCE(T1.Dept, T2.Dept, T3.Dept, T4.Dept) Dept
, COALESCE(T1.Cat, T2.Cat, T3.Cat, T4.Cat) Cat
, COALESCE(T1.Sub, T2.Sub, T3.Sub, T4.Sub) Sub
, SalesUnits, BuyUnits,  AdjustmentUnits,  DiscountAmount
FROM T1 FULL JOIN
T2 ON T2.MDate = T1.MDate AND T1.Dept = T2.Dept AND T1.Cat = T2.Cat AND T1.SubCat = T2.SubCat FULL JOIN
T3 ON T3.MDate = coalesce(T1.MDate, T2.MDate) AND T3.Dept = coalesce(T1.Dept, T2.Dept) AND T3.Cat = coalesce(T1.Cat, T2.Cat) AND T3.SubCat = coalesce(T1.SubCat, T2.SubCat) FULL JOIN
T4 ON T4.MDate = coalesce(T1.MDate, T2.MDate, T3.MDate) AND T4.Dept = coalesce(T1.Dept, T2.Dept, T3.Dept) AND T4.Cat = coalesce(T1.Cat, T2.Cat, T3.Cat) AND T4.SubCat = coalesce(T1.SubCat, T2.SubCat, T3.SubCat)
```

Comment: You can join all tables and get sum of all separate columns and use group by to collect for all unique column combinations.